# jQuery .ajax call triggering quirks mode in IE9

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

EDIT: Issue resolved using a different version of jQuery. 
I have the following ajax call

```
$.validator.addMethod("UserIDEmail", function(value, element) {
return (this.optional(element) || value.slice(-8) == "FXCM.com" || value.slice(-8) == "fxcm.com");
}, "You must use a @FXCM.com email address");
$("#FXCMLogIn").validate({
errorContainer: "#messageBox",
errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox ul",
errorElement: "li",
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('input[type="submit"]').next(".processing").show();
    var dataString = $(form).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: $(form).attr('method'),
        url: form.action,
        data: dataString,
        clearForm: true,
        success: function(data) {

            var answer = $(data).find("td:eq(3)").text();
            var message = $(data).find("td:eq(5)").text();
            if (answer==="True") {
                $("#bottomContent").load("FXCM-Conversion-Content.php #FXCMForm");

            } else {
                $('.processing').hide();
                $('input[type="text"], input[type="password"]').val("");
                $('#messageBox').show().html('<ul><li>' + message + '</li></ul>');
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
},
rules: {
    payerEmail: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        UserIDEmail: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true,
        minlength:3,
        maxlength:15
    }
},
messages: {
    payerEmail: {
        required: "Please Enter Your User ID"
    },
    password: {
        required: "Please Enter Your Password",
        minlength: "Must be at least 3 characters",
        maxlength: "Must be less than 15 characters"
    }
}
});
```

Instead of displaying the correct triggered content/page section, it switches into "Browser Mode: IE9 Document Mode:Quirks" and has this in the console "HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE9 Standards to Quirks". Both the page making the call and the pages content that is being loaded both have valid DOCTYPE's. Ive tried the meta tags`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` but to no avail. Anyone run into anything similar?

thx

Answer (score 0):

See EDIT above. Using jQuery 1.6.4 solved it. In the future will remove all .live calls and use current version of jQuery, am not able to make those changes to entire site at this time though.